# How to get the right static resource path in production environment when using vite?

Tags: vue.js, vite

When stored in the public folder, my image resources will show in  production environment as follow:

```
https://ip/static/img/xxx.png
```

But, I want it to be like this:

```
https://ip/xxx/xxx/xxx/static/img/xxx.png,
```

Because

```
https://ip/xxx/xxx/xxx/index.html
```

Which is my project path;

Could anyone tell me how to set this?

When I stored the static resource in another folder,  for example, the "static" folder, it will show in the right path after I built the project because I used the relative path

```js
../../static/img/xxx.png
```

This is my setting in vite.config.js

Besides, I can't import another resource when I used alias naming,

```js
const test = "*/xxx/xxx.png";
```

It shows:

```
https://ip//*/xxx/xxx.png
```

> *vue2.6.14, vite2.5.1*

```js
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import { createVuePlugin } from "vite-plugin-vue2";
import ViteComponents from "vite-plugin-components";
import { join } from "path";

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  base: "",
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      "@": join(__dirname, "src"),
      "~": join(__dirname, "src/components"),
      "*": join(__dirname, "static/img"),
    },
    extensions: [".js", ".vue", ".json", ".mjs"],
  },
  plugins: [createVuePlugin(), ViteComponents()],
  css: {
    preprocessorOptions: {
      less: {
        javascriptEnabled: true,
        additionalData: '@import "./src/less/varsbank.module.less";',
      },
    },
  },
  optimizeDeps: {
    include: ["axios"],
  },
  server: {
    port: 8080,
  },
  build: {
    assetsDir: "static",
  },
});
```

Thanks a million.

Answer (score 0):

> Besides, I can't import another resource when I used alias naming,
>
> `const test = "*/xxx/xxx.png";`
>
> It shows:
>
> `https://ip//*/xxx/xxx.png`

Use : `import test from "*/logo.png";`

More information :  https://vitejs.dev/guide/assets.html#static-asset-handling

Comment: thanks for your answer.  i had seen the documents, but it was not my wanted。 Is there a simpler way?